# How to find this Littlewood conjecture estimate?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Suppose Littlewood's conjecture is true. So we have $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\|n\alpha\|\|n\beta\|=0$$ for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  In particular, for some $n$ we have  $$n\|n\alpha\|\|n\beta\| < 10^{-30}$$  If finding explicitly such an $n$ is not feasible, can an estimate of it's size be found?  I am most interested in the case when $\alpha=\sqrt 2$ and $\beta=\sqrt 3$  if that helps.